# HowTo: Aquire req.ip from express server within _app.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

OS: Windows 10 Pro.
Next: 8.1.0.
Express server: 4.16.4.

So, I'm attempting to access the ctx.req property, from a custom express server, so as to gain access to req.ip, which I utilise around the site using react context, but am getting an `undefined` value response. How do I resolve this?

My code is as follows:

Usercontext.js

```html
import { createContext } from 'react';

const UserContext = createContext();

export default UserContext;
```

_app.js

```html
class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {};
    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    }
    // this exposes the query to the user
    pageProps.query = ctx.query;
    pageProps.req = ctx.req; // This line causes the site to break
    return { pageProps };
  }
  render() {
    const { Component, apollo, pageProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <Container>
        <ApolloProvider client={apollo}>
          <UserContext.Provider value={{ userip: pageProps.req }}>
            <Page>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Page>
          </UserContext.Provider>
        </ApolloProvider>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

And I access the value in each required component as follows:

```html
const somePageComponent = props => {
  const { userip } = useContext(UserContext);
}
```

I initially attempted to do `pageProps.req = ctx.req`, in `_app.js`, but that causes an `Error: Circular structure in "getInitialProps" result of page "/_error"` to occur

Server.js

```html
const app = next({ dev })

const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

const ssrCache = cacheableResponse({
  ttl: 1000 * 60 * 60, // 1hour
  get: async ({ req, res, pagePath, queryParams }) => ({
    data: await app.renderToHTML(req, res, pagePath, queryParams)
  }),
  send: ({ data, res }) => res.send(data)
})

server.set('trust proxy', true);

// Header security. See: https://observatory.mozilla.org/
server.use(helmet());

// Sets "Referrer-Policy: same-origin".
server.use(helmet.referrerPolicy({ policy: 'same-origin' }));

// Sets Feature-policy
server.use(helmet.featurePolicy({
    features: {
      fullscreen: ["'self'"],
      vibrate: ["'none'"],
      payment: ['https://yyy.com'],
      syncXhr: ["'self'"],
      geolocation: ["'self'"]
    }
}));

app.prepare().then(() => {
  //const server = express()

  server.get('*', function(req,res,next) {
    if(req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] != 'https' && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
    res.redirect('https://'+req.hostname+req.url)
    else
    next() /* Continue to other routes if we're not redirecting */
  });

  server.get('/', (req, res) => ssrCache({ req, res, pagePath: '/' }))

  server.get('*', (req, res) => handle(req, res))

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just take what you need from `req` rather than taking the whole object, which as you know, gives you an error.

For example, if you are trying to get the user's IP address from a custom header then something like this should work:

```
pageProps.userip = ctx.req.headers['x-userip']
```

...and then:

```
<UserContext.Provider value={{ userip: pageProps.userip }}>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Steve, many thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I'm getting a `Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined` error message.

Comment: When I include the line `pageProps.req = ctx.req`

Comment: And when do you get 'undefined'?

Comment: When I do `pageProps.req = ctx.req.headers[]‘

Comment: Hmm, worked fine when I tried this. What does your server code look like?

Comment: I've updated my original question to include my server.js

Comment: You might have to strip it back to the simplest possible server (even the default Next.js server) and see if it works. Then add piece by piece and see where it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const ip = appContext.ctx.req.connection.remoteAddress;
  ...
  return {
    props: {}
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const ip = context.req.headers['x-forwarded-for']
  
  return {
    props: {
      ip
    }
  }
}
```